# Passing program one output as input for program two

Tags: c++, linux, input, output, communication

I am looking to find a way to pass the output of program one to the input of program two. I have created two very simple programs to try and understand how to do this but I am having problems.

ProgramOne:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    std::cout << "Hello World!";
    return 0;
}
```

ProgramTwo (prints all arguments):

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    using namespace std;

    cout << "There are " << argc << " arguments:" << endl;

    // Loop through each argument and print its number and value
    for (int nArg=0; nArg < argc; nArg++)
        cout << nArg << " " << argv[nArg] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I have tried using the pipe command to pass the output:

```
./one | ./two
```

but my second program is only printing a single argument:

```
There are 1 arguments:
0 ./two
```

I have also tried the following command:

```
/one > ./two
```

But this results in no output from either program.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Standard input is not passed through arguments, use `cin` (similar to `cout`). And BTW, `/one > ./two` just overwrites "one" output into the the "two" file (which no longer is executable).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your way to passing output of one program to another is correct:

```
./one | ./two
```

However, it seems like you don't want to do this, and you want to pass all output of one program as command-line arguments of another.

There are multiple ways of doing this, but one of them is:

```
./two `./one`
```

(notice the backticks!)

If you want to pass it as a single argument, then try:

```
./two "`./one`"
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, many thanks! I'll accept when the time limit expires.

Comment: As an FYI, there is an alternative $(command) syntax that can be used to invoke sub commands. The dollar sign syntax is slightly better in that you don't have to worry about escaping $() unlike the tick `` marks when they are nested.

Answer (score 1):

You are very close. You can use the [xargs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/xargs.html) tool to convert standard output into a sequence of  arguments with which to invoke a subsequent program. So, for example, you can do:

```
 ./one | xargs ./two
```

And this will hopefully print out "Hello world" as an argument to program two.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the only problem is that it prints `hello` and an argument and `world` as a separate argument.

Comment: The xargs command supports a "--delimiter" argument that allows you to specify a delimiter other than whitespace (such as the newline character).